# How to use restrict text in scrapy?

Tags: python, regex, scrapy, web-crawler

My goal is to extract links only from part of a website (one HTML node).

From domain 'quotes.toscrape.com' I want to extract links which contain 'page' in them. For example: http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/3/

I tried to achieve this by passing 'page' in regular expression to following rules: allow, allow_domain and restrict_text. I used these regex combinations ( r'page', r'/page/', r'[^ ]*page[^ ]*', r'.*page.*') among others. The last two work well accroding to https://regex101.com/. None of them seems to work in my code.

Below you can see the latest execution

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'quotes.toscrape.com'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_text=r'.*page.*'), callback='parse'),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for span in response.css('span'):
            yield {
                'span': span.css('span::text').get(),
            }
        for div in response.css('div'):
            yield {
                'div': div.css('div::text').get(),
            }
        next_url_path = response.css(
            "a::attr('href')").extract()
        for item in next_url_path:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(item), callback=self.parse)
```

Excerpt from Scrapy documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

**restrict_text** (*a regular expression (or list of)*) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the link’s text must match in order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will match all links. If a list of regular expressions is given, the link will be extracted if it matches at least one.

I would appreciate a hint on how to use restrict_text correctly or any other rule to achieve same goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is true and The problem is something else.
your code has some small problems.

I changed the code to this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'quotes.toscrape.com'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'.*page.*'),
             callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        yield {'url': response.url} # It just for test. can be omitted.
        for span in response.css('span'):
            yield {
                'span': span.css('span::text').get(),
            }
        for div in response.css('div'):
            yield {
                'div': div.css('div::text').get(),
            }
```

First in `LinkExtractor` you have to use `allow=` not `restrict_text=` , because `allow=` is for urls and `restrict_text=` is for link's text, not urls.

Second, you can't call back to `parse` method because of this warning from [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules):

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic. So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer work.

So I changed the `parse` to `parse_page` and call back to it.

Third, you don't have to extract links in `parse` method and send request from there. `CrawlSpider` do that automatically. requests sent from parse method manually don't follow the `rules` you defined.

At last I suggest using this regular expression. It's simpler and more common:

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='page'),
             callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )
```

Good luck!